# How TeamCity get email address of subversion user?

Tags: email, svn, teamcity

we have continual integration for several project. Some of them are stored in git, some of them in subversion. When someone broke the build, TeamCity send an email with some details. I understand that email address of the comitee is stored in git repository. But how TeamCity get the email address of the subversion user?

Sometime it sends email, sometime not. Does it compare username of subversion and username of TeamCity login? and what about users who never haven't logged in TeamCity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's configured in user's account settings. To open it, click the arrow next to your username (in the top right corner of the screen) and select My Settings & Tools from the drop-down list. There you'll be able to manage your [VCS usernames](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Managing+your+User+Account#ManagingyourUserAccount-ManagingVersionControlUsernameSettings) and email address.